# VLC do not generate the SDP-file

Tags: windows-xp, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to get VLC (and/or libvlc) to generate a SDP file without success. I've tried various combinations and all fail.

Here is the latest attempt:

```
vlc dshow:// --plugin-path="c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins" --sout-keep --sout-all --sout=#rtp{dest=192.168.1.66,port=8833,sdp=file:///C:\test\my.sdp}
```

I've tried with `file://C:\test\my.sdp`, `file:///C:/test/my.sdp`, `file://c:/test/my.sdp` etc etc.

Have anyone got it working?

Comment: Tried using a regular `C:\test\my.sdp`?

Comment: Have you tried VLC at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing with VLC is to check the message log.  So, whne I ran the following:

```
vlc -vvv dshow:// --sout-keep --sout-all --sout=#rtp{dest=192.168.1.66,port=8833,sdp=file:///C:\test\my.sdp}
```

I got the following in my message log:

> stream_out_rtp error: missing destination and not in RTSP mode

This tells me VLC is missing the destination.  If you re-analyze the command line you'll notice that you've mistyped **dest** instead of **dst**.  So you fix the error and now run:

```
vlc -vvv dshow:// --sout-keep --sout-all --sout=#rtp{dst=192.168.1.66,port=8833,sdp=file:///C:\test\my.sdp}
```

Still no file.  It looks like the sdp output module doesn't do much output, but I can tell you from experience here that its the file path that's causing the problem.  Use only *nix style slashes in paths, so you fix the path and run:

```
vlc -vvv dshow:// --sout-keep --sout-all --sout=#rtp{dst=192.168.1.66,port=8833,sdp=file:///C:/test/my.sdp}
```

And, assuming the permissions are setup correctly in the C:\test directory you should get your sdp file.

Comment: where can I find the log?

Comment: Tools->Messages

Comment: This just got a "notable question" badge. Weird that my +1 is the only one. Doesn't the solution work for them, or what do you think?